# In Perl - How to know the array size in bytes?

Tags: arrays, perl, byte

I Have stored a decoded json in an array. I need to know the array size in bytes, so that I can parse it. Please suggest me a way to know the size of an array in perl.

Note: It is not the number of elements in array. I want size in bytes or mb

Comment: What will you use this size for? Why would you “parse” the array if the JSON was already decoded into an array? It feels like there's a lot of context missing in this question. Ideally, please [edit] the question to include some code that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: [Devel::Size](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/Devel-Size-0.81/lib/Devel/Size.pm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290816/how-to-get-size-of-array-in-bytes-in-perl)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Devel::Size qw(total_size);

my @arr = (1, 2, 3, "Foo", "Bar", "Baz", [4, 5, 6], {xyz => 2048});

print "Size: ", total_size(\@arr), " bytes.\n";
```

You would therefore need [Devel::Size](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/Devel-Size-0.81/lib/Devel/Size.pm)

If you are unsure on how to install modules from CPAN, go to [this link](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

Comment: If I use use Devel::Size qw(total_size); - It is showing me error. Can't locate Devel/Size.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .)

Comment: @SubhashreeR Ok, read the answer again, you need to install the Devel::Size module from CPAN. There is a link in the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @SubhashreeR see the edited answer, I posted a link that will help you to install modules if you are unsure how to.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Just out of curiosity (and because I don't want to install D::S right now): what's the output of your code sample? How many bytes is it?

Comment: Oops, I found it in the example link you provided:  it's 765 bytes. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @PerlDuck Yes. My output when I ran it is the same as the linked answer 765 bytes.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thanks for your suggestion. Referred your link and used it, it is working fine.